# Mysql put duplicate rows of a query in 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with

```
SELECT `prodcutos`.`id`,
`prodcutos`.`nombre`,
`prodcutos`.`sku`,
`prodcutos`.`marca`,
`prodcutos`.`precio`,
`prodcutos`.`imagen`,
`prodcutos`.`descripcion`,
`prodcutos`.`categoria1`,
`prodcutos`.`categoria2`,
`prodcutos`.`categoria3`
FROM `Syscom`.`prodcutos`;
```

with a query i get duplicate sku but diferente categoria2, categoria3

```
'2948', 'Licencia', 'XPETBL', 'MILESTONE', '1,999', 'XPETBL.png', 'Description', 'CCTV', 'NVR Grabación', 'Licencias'

'3425', 'Licencia', 'XPETBL', 'MILESTONE', '1,999', 'XPETBL.png', 'Description', 'CCTV', 'Software', 'Grabación'
```

Can i create a query that get me the next result

```
'2948', 'Licencia', 'XPETBL', 'MILESTONE', '1,999', 'XPETBL.png', 'Description', 'CCTV', 'NVR Grabación', 'Licencias', 'CCTV', 'Software', 'Grabación'
```

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: GROUP BY some_field, in your example GROUP BY CATEGORY(or  SKU....)

Comment: The group by is the SKU

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `prodcutos`.`id`,
`prodcutos`.`nombre`,
`prodcutos`.`sku`,
`prodcutos`.`marca`,
`prodcutos`.`precio`,
`prodcutos`.`imagen`,
`prodcutos`.`descripcion`,
`prodcutos`.`categoria1`,
`prodcutos`.`categoria2`,
`prodcutos`.`categoria3`
FROM `Syscom`.`prodcutos`
GROUP BY categoria1,categoria2,categaria3;
```

Comment: I cant use group by
I need to create a new row with the duplicated rows
I need all the results in 1 row